# How to select <T> in static function

Tags: c#

I have a class Student , inside there is a property `Studentname` and `address` .

I also have a static function like below for me to filter student by `address(living area)`

```
public static List<T> FilterByAddress<T>(List<T> StudentList, string address )
    {
       Type typeParameterType = typeof(T); // it is returning Student 
       StudentList = StudentList.FindAll(x => x.address == address );            
       return StudentList;
    }
```

I am getting an error on this part of code "x.address" which is Error   42 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Studentname' and no extension method 'Studentname' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

how can I solve this by making T recognize as the student class ?

Comment: If `T` *must be* a `Student`, you really shouldn't using generics in this method.

Comment: The T can be different not necessary must be student , it be other class than have a property Address. so i hope this function can used  for classes that have property Address

Answer (score 4):

**Update** Based on your comment:

> The T can be different not necessary must be student , it be other class than have a property Address

Generic do not work this way. If you want to access a common `Address` property on multiple classes using a single method, you need to have them all implement an interface like `IHasAddress` (terrible name) and then define a generic constraint on your method like `where T : IHasAddress`

**Original answer**

If you need it to be a `Student`, you shouldn't make the method generic:

```
public static List<Student> FilterByAddress(List<Student> StudentList, string address )
{
   StudentList = StudentList.FindAll(x => x.address == address );            
   return StudentList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that T is generic and has no concept of Address you need to close the compilers options for T to say it's atleast a 'Student '

```
public static List<T> FilterByAddress<T>(List<T> StudentList, string address ) where T: Student
    {
       Type typeParameterType = typeof(T); // it is returning Student 
       StudentList = StudentList.FindAll(x => x.address == address );            
       return StudentList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add constraint to generic method:

```
public static List<T> FilterByAddress<T>(List<T> StudentList, string address )
where T:Student
```